# Sorting a specific column

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array `items[]` which has four fields `name`, `origin`, `destination`, `seats`.
I would like to sort the name alphabatically onClick of the table heading i.e `Name`

heres my snippet of code

JS file with array declaration variables and passing the values to form.js

Stuff.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tab from './Table';
import Form from './Form';

class Stuff extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      origin: '',
        destination: '',
          seats: '',
      items: []
    }
  };

  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let items = [...this.state.items];

    items.push({
      name: this.state.name,
      origin: this.state.origin,
      destination: this.state.destination,
      seats: this.state.seats
    });

    this.setState({
      items,
      name: '',
      origin: '',
      destination: '',
      seats: ''
    });
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let input = e.target;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = input.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Form handleFormSubmit={ this.handleFormSubmit }
          handleInputChange={ this.handleInputChange }
          newName={ this.state.name }
          newOrigin={ this.state.origin }
          newDestination={ this.state.destination }
          newSeats={ this.state.seats } />
<Tab items={ this.state.items }/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stuff;
```

Table.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';

class Tab extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;



  return (

      <Table striped>
             <thead>
               <tr>

                 <th  >Name</th>
                 <th>Origin</th>
                 <th>Destination</th>
                 <th>Seats</th>

               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             {items.map(item => {
  return (

               <tr>

                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                 <td>{item.origin}</td>
                 <td>{item.destination}</td>
                 <td>{item.seats}</td>

               </tr>
             );
           })}

             </tbody>
           </Table>

    );
  }
}


export default Tab;
```

Is there any way that when I click on Name Heading in my table it would sort according to the name?

Thank You

Comment: Share your approach for making the sort happen.

Comment: I was thinking of-   compare(a, b) {
    // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
    const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();

    let comparison = 0;
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (nameA < nameB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
  }

  items.sort(compare);
  but the problem is that the name is a part of items array and i cant figure out how to use that specific part from items array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your query:

```
const items = [
    {
    name: 'C',
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'A',
    quantity: 8
  }
];

console.log(items);

items.sort((a,b) => {
    const name1 = a.name.toLowerCase(), name2 = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return name1 === name2 ? 0 : name1 < name2 ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(items);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abhikr713/r6L2npfL/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't go into details of ReactJS, you need to implement yourself. The idea is quite simple:

1. You create a event handler for header like (onClick)="sortByName()"
2. Define your function sortByName by passing your data into it, and sort it manually, you can use Array.sort() to achieve this.
3. Update the state will make React re-render the part have the update