# Storing array into localstorage in React

Tags: javascript

I have an array items[] in which I am inputting 4 keys with values coming from input box.

I now have the values in the array but on page refresh the values are reset, So I was thinking of using localStorage for this i tried -

```js
  localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(items));
```

and for retrieving it i tried -

```js
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("test");
var test2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, the values are still disappearing after refresh

new code-

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';

class Tab extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;

    items.sort((a,b) => {
        const name1 = a.name.toLowerCase(), name2 = b.name.toLowerCase();
        return name1 === name2 ? 0 : name1 < name2 ? -1 : 1;
    });

  localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(items));
  var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("test");
  var test2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

  return (

      <Table striped>
             <thead>
               <tr>

                 <th  >Name</th>
                 <th>Origin</th>
                 <th>Destination</th>
                 <th>Seats</th>

               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             {test2.map(item => {
  return (

               <tr>

                 <td>{item.name}</td>
                 <td>{item.origin}</td>
                 <td>{item.destination}</td>
                 <td>{item.seats}</td>

               </tr>
             );
           })}

             </tbody>
           </Table>

    );
  }
}


export default Tab;
```

Comment: you could check it in devtools > application > local storage, if the value is there, though you probably did. And make sure `setItem` is called

Comment: I checked in local storage its showing up the values there but upon refresh its not reloading them back

Comment: are you sure `items` has _items_ in it?

Comment: yup  i think the var test2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData); is not working because in devtools it shows the values stored in test not test 2

Comment: it's not clear then, could you show more code?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko Hi, this link has the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578726/sorting-a-specific-column

Comment: @AnandTrivedi it doesnt mention local storage

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko ya, sorry I have edited the new code into the main post above

Comment: you should not be using localStorage inside of render method

Comment: looks like you are overriding items in local storage with some empty default array

Answer (score 0):

You need to check a condition before set the values in `localstorage`. like,

```
if(localStorage.getItem("test") === undefined)
{
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Because when you refresh your page. on load function may clear the array and set that empty array values into the local storage again.

### Edit:

You can do it by using a global flag variable  as `IsNewData`. When you submit new data set `IsNewData == true` and do `IsNewData == false` after completion of submitting. Also add the additional condition in the if statement :)

```
if(localStorage.getItem("test") === undefined ||  IsNewData)
{
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Comment: you mean don't `setItem` if items is empty? it's `if (items && items.length) localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(items))` then

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko Yes. If the localstorage has vales, then why we need to reassign it?

Comment: what if items gets changes? the local storage wont be updated

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko LocalStorage only accept string values not array values directly. did you see `JSON.stringify(items)` while set the values in local storage

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko At the time you don't need to check that condition.

Comment: @RameshRajendran hey, I tried the if condition what it does is keeping the first value i entered(upon refresh) and it is also displaying it in the table which is the ultimate goal. but after that I am not able to submit any more new values in the forms

Comment: `after that I am not able to submit any more new values in the forms`. Then you are missing something.

Comment: @AnandTrivedi I have edited my question with a key point. Please find it

Comment: @RameshRajendran Hi, I read your edited part, I am currently figuring out the global flag variables as I do not have much experience with react. Ill update you after hopefully i do that